# calling a javascript function when user clicks 'X' to close a form

Tags: asp.net, javascript, webforms

I already have a 'Close' button that calls some javascript function.  However, if the user just clicks the 'X' to close, the function is never called.

Any way to call a function when 'X' is clicked, or hide the 'X'?

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about jquery dialog ? can we see your code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "`onbeforeunload`" javascript event to catch when the user attempts to close the browser or navigate away.

```
<html> 
<head>
<title>< /title>
</head>

<body onbeforeunload="alert('Closing');">
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the (non-standard) [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event